# If I throw an exception in a getter of a property, can I obtain the name of the property in a catch block?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, exception, stack-trace

If I throw an exception from a getter of a property, is it possible to obtain the name of

the property in the catch block where I have called that property -like using reflection or

reading the stack trace?

For instance:

```
class Animal
{
  private string _name;
  public string Name {

           get { throw new Exception(); } 

           set { _name = value; }
                     }
}
```

And in another place, I call the Name property's getter and I want to obtain the property name in the catch block:

```
Animal cat = new Animal();

try{ 
    string catName = cat.Name;
   }

catch (Exception e)
   {

    string propertyName = //Here I should be able to reach "Name"  

   }
```

Comment: Don't throw exceptions in the getter of a property.

Comment: whats the point, what are you trying to do, and why?

Comment: I like to know too why you think you need this. I bet there is something wrong with your design if you need this.

Comment: I'm hoping its for error logging purposes!

Answer (score 0):

it will show in your stack trace as exception in get_Name() method. you can probably parse it to get the Property Name

Comment: Can you elaborate it on the example in the question, pls?

Comment: see @Mongus answer..Your Property when compiled will be changed to get_'PropertyName(basically getter and setter methods).

Answer (score 0):

You could parse `e.StackTrace` using a Regex :

```
    try
    {
            int x = this.Ong;
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
            Console.WriteLine ( Regex.Match ( ex.StackTrace, @"get_(?<prop>.*)\(\)" ).Groups["prop"].Value );
    }
```

**Note** You should put more error checking on the Regex above as `Groups["prop"]` may be null if the exception isn't raised from a property.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options, non of which are great:

1. Parse the get_Name() method from the `Exception.StackTrace` property, as Ashley and Mongus describe. This will fail when the getter gets inlined (which is not unlikely to happen), because inlined methods calls will (obviously) not show up in the stacktrace.
2. Throw a special exception that contains that property name:

   ```
   public string PropertyName
   {
       get { throw new PropertyException("PropertyName", "Ex message.");
   }
   ```

   This however isn't great either, since you should explicitly throw this type of exception. So failures from deeper down the callstack must be wrapped in that `PropertyException`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're considering something like this you most likely would be far better off implementing something like the `INotifyPropertyChanged` and stick this as part of your getter instead of only caring about the setter like normal usage.

[How to: Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[`Exception.TargetSite`](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.targetsite)

Answer (score 0):

Since C# 5, you can use [CallerMemberNameAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public class SomeCustomException : Exception
{
    public string PropertyName { get; }

    public SomeCustomException(string propertyName) 
        : base($"Property {propertyName} was null)
    {
        this.PropertyName = propertyName;
    }
}

public class Animal
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { Throw(); }
    }

    private static void Throw([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        // propertyName will be 'Name'
        throw new CustomException(propertyName);
    }
}
```

I could have put `[CallerMemberName]` directly on the constructor for `SomeCustomException`, but that seems unnecessarily ugly: the exception doens't need to know that it will be called from the property getter, hence the separate static `Throw` method.